# making a call to http://localhost to warm up the server

Tags: ashx

I was just wondering how can I fire an synchronous call to http://localhost to keep the server warmed up from the ashx handler?

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       //warm up codes come here

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        context.Response.Write(@"warming up local server.");

    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Just for clarification, you want a synchronous call to the ASP.NET HTTP Handler?

Comment: you could write a polling windows service or a scheduled task. But why do you want to do this? Is the load time too long?

Comment: yes a call to localhost to warm the server since it takes a long time for the site to load for the first time. A load balance will call the ashx handler periodically.

Comment: i got the solution myself.thanks anyway.

Comment: How did you solve it?